# Recovering projection information after reduction Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

Is there a way to reproject the resulting image after a reduction so that we can use the geometry of the image for another operation?

I am using `image.reproject()` but when calculating the `image.geometry()` I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the link to the script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1435eedcfff6d9a84e305df2267e2e26

And the script:

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-93.68530048461537,37.399409695581674],
[-93.69628681274037,36.781581043994294],
[-92.76244892211537,36.78598052408677],
[-92.78442157836537,37.40813695578065],
[-93.68530048461537,37.399409695581674]]])

var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T')
  .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-30')
  .filterBounds(geometry)

//Compute NDVI
var ndvi_images = landsat.map(function(image){
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('ndvi') 
})

//Calculate max NDVI
var maxNDVI = ndvi_images.max()

//Reproject
var reprojected = maxNDVI.reproject('EPSG:32615', null, null)

//Remove edges
var clipped_image = reprojected.clip(reprojected.geometry().buffer(-6000))

print(clipped_image)
```

Comment: Please, paste the error message as text (because it is searchable), not picture. And specific about that red picture, it hurt my eyes. Tks.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work as the geometry of the reprojected image is not bounded somewhere, in other words, it is a continuous polygon over the whole world. Therefore, you cannot use a buffer and/or use it to clip an image.

You can check the unbounded geometry of your image using:

```
//Reproject
var reprojected = maxNDVI.reproject('EPSG:32615', null, 30);
print('geometry unbounded image (=the whole world)', reprojected.geometry());
Map.addLayer(reprojected.geometry(), {color: 'red'}, 'unbounded geometry', 1, 0.3);
```

To do what you probably want, first clip the image on the geometry you defined, and use reproject and remove edges on the image.

```
// first clip to image to get a bounded geometry
reprojected = maxNDVI.clip(geometry).reproject('EPSG:32615', null, 30);
//Remove edges
var clipped_image = reprojected.clip(reprojected.geometry().buffer(-6000));
```

A general note on reprojection inside the Google Earth Engine: [link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections).

[link script](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections)

Comment: This solves the problem with the lost projection, thank you.
However, I have a new problem: when clipping the image with a geometry feature which is larger than the image's extent, the new geometry of the image is inherited from the feature used for clipping. How can we recover the geometry of the actual image’s extent? In other words, is there a way to “bound” the geometry to the valid pixels in the image?

Comment: I uess you just want image.geometry(). Then you can combine the image geometry with the geometry of interest with: image.geometry().intersection(geometry).

Comment: I am sorry my question was not very clear. The geometry of interest is the geometry of the image's extent. However when clipping the image with a feature which is larger than the image's extent, the new geometry of the image (image.geometry()) corresponds to the geometry of the clipping feature (feature.geometry()) (therefore larger than the image's extent). How could I recover the geometry of the actual image's extent?

Comment: Use  image.geometry().intersection(geometry) before you clip the image